# MySQL's LIKE in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'd like to filter several SPANs with the text they contain:

```
$('spanFilter').filter(function(){
    var html = $(this).html();
    return //comparison html LIKE %asdf%
});
```

In the comparison, I'm trying to do something like MySQL's LIKE:

```
field LIKE %asdf%
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
field LIKE %asdf%
```

can work like

```
$("span:contains('asdf')")
```

[:contains(text)](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/contains) - Matches elements which contain the given text.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what it is you're after but you can use the `:contains()` selector. For example:

```
$('spanFilter').filter(function(){
    var html = $(this).html();
    $("span:contains(asdf)", this).addClass('highlight");
});
```

Comment: Did you meant not to use variable 'html'?

Comment: Come to think of it, the html variable is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this:

1. Simple: using indexOf

   return html.indexOf('asdf') >= 0;
2. Complex: use RegExp

   return /asdf/.test(html);

Note that RegExp are more powerful and can match different texts.
[Here's a guide about them.](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/regexp.shtml)